# Readstream return cant handle error event even though it is there

Tags: node.js, fs

Here is the code

```
function read_csv(file_name){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let output = []
    fs.createReadStream(file_name)
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (row) => {
        output.push(row)            
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        resolve(output.slice(1))
    })
    .on('error', function(err) {
        reject(err.message)
    });
})
```

}

Even though error event is handled, it still throw

```
events.js:288
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'goodvisit.csv'
  Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
  at internal/fs/streams.js:132:12
  at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:154:23) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'goodvisit.csv'
  }
```

I tried another way of declaring a variable for fs.createReadstream, although it would work for above scenario, but then I can get data properly.

Comment: `pipe` returns its parameter `csv()`, so you bind the error handler to `csv()`, not  `fs.createReadStream(file_name)`

Comment: something like this `csv().on('error', err => reject(err.message));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Node, a pipe does not forward error to the next pipe. So, you need to attach the handler to the `fs` as there is no such file that you are trying to read.

```
fs.createReadStream(file_name).on('error', err => console.log(err))
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (row) => {
        output.push(row)            
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        resolve(output.slice(1))
    })
    .on('error', function(err) {
        reject(err.message)
    });

    fs
```

You can check [this](https://medium.com/developers-arena/streams-piping-and-their-error-handling-in-nodejs-c3fd818530b6) link for more details, how to can handle errors when we pipe ours streams multiple times.

If this doesn't work you can use [multipipe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multipipe) to combinate several streams and handle error at one place.

```
const pipe = require('multipipe')

// pipe multiple streams like A, B and C
const stream = pipe(A, B, C) 


// centralized error handling
stream.on('error', fn)
```

Comment: it throwing error that fs.on is not a function

Comment: Updated the code there was a code format issue.